# jQuery - How do I prevent for a second paragraph to be highlighted when one is already highlighted ("clicked")

Tags: jquery, paragraph

I have two functions, one creates paragraphs dynamically and the other function selects ("changes background color") and deselects ("changes to default background color"). The problem I have is that I can select all paragraphs at the same time and I want to be able to select one paragraph at a time, of course, after deselecting the already selected paragraph.

How do I prevent another paragraph to be selected/highlighted when there is one already selected/highlighted?

You can check out the full source code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2QqmN/1/

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 1;
$("#add").on(
    "click", function(){
        $("#a").append('<p>Paragraph ' + count + '</p>');
    count++;

    });
$("#a").on("click", "p", function(){ 
var bg = $(this).css("background-color");


    if(bg=="rgb(255, 255, 255)") {  
        $(this).css({"background-color":"green", "color":"white"});

    } 

 else { 

  $(this).css({"background-color":"white","color":""});


 }
    });



});
```

If I was clear enough, please help!
You will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a flag, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 1, flag = false;
    $("#add").on("click", function(){
         $("#a").append('<p>Paragraph ' + count + '</p>');
         count++;
   });
   $("#a").on("click", "p", function(){ 
        var bg = $(this).css("background-color");
        if(bg=="rgb(255, 255, 255)") {  
            if (flag==false) {
               $(this).css({"background-color":"green", "color":"white"});
               flag=true;
            }
        } else { 
             $(this).css({"background-color":"white","color":""});
             flag=false;
       }
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2QqmN/2/)

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for, I would never have thought to add a flag since I am new to jquery. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You should use css to style your selected items. Each selected item can be given a css class "selected". On click, you can remove that class from all elements, then add the class to the element clicked on.

```
.selected { background-color: green; color: white; }
```

For the javascript:

```
var count = 1;
$("#add").on("click", function() {
    $("#a").append('<p>Paragraph ' + count + '</p>');
    count++;
});

$("#a").on("click", "p", function() {
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2QqmN/6/

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand the question. From what I can gather, you want only one paragraph to be selected at any given time, but the ability to add *n* paragraphs. If this is the case, I believe the following accomplishes this:

```
$( "#a" ).on( "click", "p", activateParagraph );
$( "#add" ).on( "click", addParagraph );

function addParagraph () {
  $( "<p>", { text: 'Paragraph ' + $( "#a p" ).length++ } )
    .appendTo( "#a" ); 
}

function activateParagraph () {
  $( this )
    .addClass( "on" )
    .siblings( ".on" )
      .removeClass( "on" );
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uziheg/2/edit